# NSLayout Constraints failing

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout

So i'm trying to programatically add constraints to my view using the following code. I'm trying to add some top space of 32 and some leading space of 16 to a view which is being added programatically to one of my view controllers but i seems to be running into some issues.

Below is the example of how i'm returning the button to my view so it can be added programatically.

```
// Creating the button
func createDismissButton(vwParentView: OnboardingViewController) -> UIButton {

     let dismissButton = UIButton()
     dismissButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Close"), forState: .Normal)
     dismissButton.frame =  CGRectMake(16, 32, 34, 34)
     dismissButton.addTarget(self, action: "dismiss:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

     // AUTO LAYOUT

    // WIDTH & HEIGHT
    let dismissWidthButtonConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint (item: dismissButton,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: nil,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 34)

    let dismissHeightButtonConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint (item: dismissButton,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: nil,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 34)

    // SPACING
    let dismissButtonTopConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: dismissButton,
        attribute: .Top,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: vwParentView.view,
        attribute: .Top,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 32)

    let dismissButtonLeftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: dismissButton,
        attribute: .Leading,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: vwParentView.view,
        attribute: .Leading,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 16)


    dismissButton.addConstraint(dismissWidthButtonConstraint)
    dismissButton.addConstraint(dismissHeightButtonConstraint)

    dismissButton.addConstraint(dismissButtonTopConstraint)
    dismissButton.addConstraint(dismissButtonLeftConstraint)

     return dismissButton
}
```

But it seems to be failing on the spacing i add `vwParentView.view`since it was bring up an error in the log about the item property having to be a view. But now when i run the code with the these properties i'm getting the following error.

***'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.'***

I'm trying to add this button to a view which has also been created programatically like so below.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    // Add the view below to the current view controller
    self.view.addSubview(generatePurchasePaging().view)
}

func generatePurchasePaging() -> OnboardingViewController {

    let welcomePage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "PAY WHAT YOU WANT", body: "I made my app so you could have the best experience reading tech related news. That’s why I want you to value it based on your satisfaction.", image: UIImage(named: "Purchase-Pig"), buttonText: "") { () -> Void in

    }

    let firstPurchasePage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "MINT", body: "The app is great but there’s still a few places in room of improvement. If this is your feeling this is for you.", image: UIImage(named: "Purchase-Mint"), buttonText: "69p") { () -> Void in

    }

    let secondPurchasePage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "SWEET", body: "IThis is the suggested price where you value the time I spent on development and design. Feel free to pay more or less.", image: UIImage(named: "Purchase-Lolly"), buttonText: "£1.49") { () -> Void in

    }

    let thirdPurchasePage = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "GOLD", body: "Hello is it me your looking for, if this popped into your mind using the app then this is the price for you.", image: UIImage(named: "Purchase-Coin"), buttonText: "£2.99") { () -> Void in

    }

    let purchaseVC = OnboardingViewController(backgroundImage: nil, contents: [welcomePage, firstPurchasePage, secondPurchasePage, thirdPurchasePage])
   purchaseVC.shouldMaskBackground = false

    purchaseVC.view.addSubview(createDismissButton(purchaseVC))
    return purchaseVC
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few thoughts:

1. When you programmatically create a view, [`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) defaults to `true`. Turn this off.
2. You are setting constraints to another view (its superview?) before adding it to the view hierarchy. So make sure (a) you first perform `addSubiew` and (b) this constraint should be added to the nearest common parent (usually the superview), not to the button, itself. The `.NotAnAttribute` constraints can be added to the button, but the rest should be added to the nearest common parent.
3. You are setting both the constraints and the `frame`. If you do the former, the latter is not needed.

If it's still not working after you remedy the above, please share the full text of the error, not just the one-line message.

Comment: Hey rob thanks for the reply, so if i was to just set the frame i wouldn't need the constraints? Because i was worried on different devices it would be positioned differently

Comment: Either turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` and add constraints or leave `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on and set `frame` (and the auto sizing mask). Nowadays, you generally do the former.